# Display AdvancedMarkerElement in street view

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can I render a `google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement` in google street view? My marker is rendered fine on the default map, but disappears when switching to street view.

I'm using React and following the approach set out in this video tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kxYqoY2WwE

Comment: It is [not supported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/282790637). Google knows it and seems reluctant to implement. Your best option is to star the issue (possibly add a comment and explain your use case and why you would need it). Wait and pray.

Comment: Please help upvote this [feature request](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/282790637), thank you!